# Prepaid Debit Card for traveling in Europe from Israeli bank

Tags: money, payment-cards, pre-pay, israeli-citizens, forex-cards

I would like to buy Prepaid Debit Card for traveling in Europe. However, if I understood it correctly, I should choose the company regarding the country of my current residence. Not all companies offer their services to all countries (I am in Israel ). So far I found only two companies [payoneer](http://www.payoneertravel.com/)  and [western union](https://www.wuprepaid.com/wuprepaid/public/login.do). I found those two by chance on the Internet, of course there are maybe more that work in Israel. I expected to find any information regarding the dealers on sites of Visa and Mastercard, however there was no anything useful.

Please, if you more experienced, advise me which company to choose based on fees and others conditions. Maybe you know another company with better conditions which provides service in Israel.

Comment: Most banks and travel agencies in Israel should offer prepaid travel credit cards. I've used a couple that were branded in this manner (though neither purchased in Israel), but both were essentially rebranding a "travelex cash passport" card. I'd suggest looking at some local bank and travel agency websites as a starting point.

Comment: Level of service in israeli banks are still very low. It looks like they stopped their development in 19th century. I asked representatives in few big domestic banks about "prepaid card", they answered "we don't what are you talking about". In addition, western union provides it's prepaid service only in US. The last hope is payoneer

Comment: @fog - any chance you found one??

Answer (score 2):

There are very few options in Israel for this type of cards but there probably even fewer ones in English.

The ones I found so far would be from [Israel Post](http://www.israelpost.co.il/content.nsf/pages/visa_dollar_prepaid_en?OpenDocument), although it does seem that you can only reload the card at a postal branch in Israel.

And [Net+](http://www.neteller.com/netplusprepaidcard/) which is a UK company but supposedly available in Israel.